# Although they said nothing, she could sense their disapproval of her suggestion

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

why is the preposition of `disapproval` in the sentence "Although they said nothing, she could sense their disapproval of her suggestion." is `of`? Not `for` instead?

Also for the verb `disapprove`, the preposition used after the word is also `of` , as in "I strongly disapprove of underage drinking." why is that?

Comment: Because the verb "disapprove" requires a prepositional phrase headed by "of" as a complement. The same way the verb "depend" requires a PP headed by "on".

Comment: @user178049 yea I know but why?

Comment: @Joji : Many times the idiomatic preposition we match with a particular verb is really a matter of convention and not subject to reasoning, rules, or "why". We use "disapprove-of" and "depend-on", just because that's what we are used to hearing. Sometimes the choice of preposition varies regionally as well.

Comment: @joji: because that is part of the dictionary entry for the verb _approve_. It is as much a part of the word, and just as unpredictable, as the sounds that the word is made of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree of course with other members' comments that "of", just like most other prepositions, is idiomatic when used after verbs like "approve" and "disapprove". However, OP's question is in line with some grammarians (like Seth Lindstromberg, author of "English Prepositions Explained") who claim that, idiomatic as they are, prepositions tend to follow certain semantic patterns.

In my experience as a teacher, students need to have some references to remember which prepositions follow which words, be them verbs, adjectives, or nouns, and if possible group them and find some features in common.

I find at least two reasons which can account for the presence of "of" in this case. One is that "of" can introduce the subject-matter, being similar to (though not replaceable with) "regarding". We have some cases in which the "of"-phrase will immediately follow the verb, and others in which it will come after an object:

- think **of** something
- dream **of** something
- remind somebody **of** something
- suspect somebody **of** something
- accuse somebody **of** something
- convict somebody **of** something

Another reason is that "of" after certain abstract nouns introduces the object (in this case, whatever receives their disapproval). What is curious here is that in some cases "of" will subsist after the verbs, while in other cases "of" is only used after the noun:

- They **approve/disapprove of** her suggestion -> their **approval/disapproval of** her suggestion
- They **accept** her plans -> their **acceptance of** her plans
- They **indicate** a course of action -> their **indication of** a course of action
- They **criticize** her ideas -> their **criticism of** her ideas
- They **reject** her proposal -> their **rejection of** her proposal

Answer (score 2):

Particular verbs require their prepositional phrases to have particular prepositions. There is frequently no real logic to this. You just need to learn which verbs take which sorts of prepositional phrases. One (dis)approves or thinks **of** things, speculates or thinks **about** things (or occasionally **on** things), depends **on** things, reasons ***with*** people, dances **to** a piece of music, and so on.

Comment: If @Joji (or anyone else) wanted to research the historical origins\reasons of why one preposition becomes part of a particular verb, would you have any recommendations @SamBC?

Comment: @DonB. I'm afraid I'm no linguist, just an educated native.